# What is wrong with my following LED code for raspberry pi3?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3

So I have implemented a basic Client-Server communication , my computer being the client and raspberry pi3 the server.
I am trying to run a code where by default it runs traffic signal light in red-yellow-green order in a loop until my computer runs a python code that sends a signal to my raspberry pi which will be listening to a common port, on the signal being received the code should only light up green led while the other two are made low and if there are no further signals, then it should go back to executing red-yellow-green in a loop until the next interrupt.

I've tried many things but the common theme is either the code does not move until `c, addr = s.accept()` is fulfiled or the if loop consisting of default red-yellow-green execution in a loop never runs but on interrupt the else loop is executed. Also tried having `if (c, addr = s.accept())` in one line but i always got a syntax error. EDITED:  This exact version of the code fails to execute the if loop but successfully executes the else loop.

```
import socket
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
s = socket.socket()
host = '' #ip of raspberry pi
port = 12345
s.bind((host, port))
#while True:
while True:

    c=0
    s.listen(5)
    c, addr = s.accept()       
    if c==0:
        import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
        import time
        GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
        GPIO.setwarnings(False)
        GPIO.setup(18, GPIO.OUT)
        GPIO.setup(23, GPIO.OUT)
        GPIO.setup(24, GPIO.OUT)
            # Red
        GPIO.output(18,GPIO.HIGH)
        time.sleep(2)
                # yellow
        GPIO.output(18,GPIO.LOW)
        GPIO.output(23,GPIO.HIGH)

        time.sleep(1)
                # Green
        GPIO.output(18,GPIO.LOW)
        GPIO.output(23,GPIO.LOW)
        GPIO.output(24,GPIO.HIGH)
        time.sleep(2)

        GPIO.output(24,GPIO.LOW)       

    else:
        print ('Got connection from',addr)
        import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
        import time
        GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
        GPIO.setwarnings(False)
        GPIO.setup(24,GPIO.OUT)
        GPIO.setup(18, GPIO.OUT)
        GPIO.setup(23, GPIO.OUT)
        print ("Green LED on")
        GPIO.output(24,GPIO.HIGH)
        GPIO.output(18,GPIO.LOW)
        GPIO.output(23,GPIO.LOW)
        c.send('Ambulance was detected')
        time.sleep(1)
        print ("LED off")
        GPIO.output(24,GPIO.LOW)
        c.close()
```

Expected : By default red-yellow-green lit up one after another but on receiving a signal it should immediately only light up green and then resume in the same r-y-g loop. 
Actual result: Unable to run r-y-g in a loop but i am able to light up green led on interrupt. Any solution? Thanks!

Comment: You give many examples of ways your code failed in different versions, but that is irrelevant: please only give us, in a detailed way, how **this** exact version of the code fails. Note that without that, it is very difficult to know what is wrong, especially as your code depends on some hardware that we generally don't have, which makes it almost impossible to test.

Comment: Sorry, it has been edited , thank you.

Comment: **First**, remove the duplicate `import RPi.GPIO as GPIO; import time` from your `loop`. **Second**, move this `GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM); GPIO.setwarnings(False); GPIO.setup(...` outside the `loop`, call it only **once**. Define functions, e.g. `def green():`, for all colors. **Third**, add `print(c)` before `if c==0:`.